# Variable showing as undefined straight after it's been initialized

Tags: php, slim

Maybe I'm just too tired to be programming, but could someone tell me why this prints `user doesn't exist`?

```
// Create user class to hold session data
$user = new stdClass();

function init () {
    if (!isset($user)) echo 'user doesn\'t exist';
}

init();
```

Comment: see [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the manual.

Comment: You are too tired to be programming any more.  You might not be too tired to be writing unit tests, though.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I've been writing JS most of today so got used to being able to access global variable within functions without trouble. (facepalm).

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue with the variable scope, the variable cannot be accessed by the function init, try using the global key word
    // Create user class to hold session data
    $user = new stdClass();

```
function init () {
    global $user;
    if (!isset($user)) echo 'user doesn\'t exist';
}

init();
```